# Python Discord Bot - Post a message to a specific channel when a function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I'm trying to define a function that will post a message to a specific discord channel when the function is called. I have no idea how to do it. This is what I have so far. Can someone help out?

edit: I need it to run whenever the output() function is called, regardless of other events.

```
import discord
import asyncio

token = 'BOT TOKEN'
channelid = 'CHANNEL ID'

client = discord.Client()

def respond(output):
 #this should make a discord bot send a message with a value of output to the channel of channelid

client.run(token)
respond('hello world')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bot.get_channel(channelid).

This is just an example sorry for the bad formatting I'm not got with formatting in stack-overflow. :

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event

async def on_ready():

    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

    channel = bot.get_channel(yourchannelid) #a specific channel

    await channel.send('Bot is ready')
```

Comment: Hope it helped.